# List transformation based on multiple conditions

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

Given a list of numerical values

```
a={0.02, 1.7, 0.25, 0.16, 0.24, 0.4, 0.46, 0.38, 0.21}
```

construct a corresponding list based on the set of criteria

> if [ai] < 0.05 assign -> p1,
>      0.05 <= [ai]< 0.15 -> p2,
>      0.15 <= [ai]< 0.25 -> p3,
>      0.25 <= [ai]< 0.45 -> p4,
>      [ai]=> 0.45        -> p5

The expected output would be a list
b={p1,p5,p4,p3.....}

Comment: How about constructing a `Function` with `Piecewise` and `Map`ping it over the list?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: What is `[ai]`? Is it `a[[i]]`?  Some familiarity with *Mathematiica* is expected, but this does not show much: is this a question about using the software system *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f = x \[Function] Piecewise[{
     {p1, x < 0.05},
     {p2, 0.5 <= x < 0.15},
     {p3, 0.15 <= x < 0.25},
     {p4, 0.25 <= x < 0.45}
     },
    p5 (*default value*)
    ];

a = {0.02, 1.7, 0.25, 0.16, 0.24, 0.4, 0.46, 0.38, 0.21};
f /@ a
```

> {p1, p5, p4, p3, p3, p4, p5, p4, p3}

Comment: Thank you so much !  I am embarrassed to say how much time I was scratching my head.

Comment: Michael - I fully agree with you.  I just started...... Sorry for such fundamental error.

Comment: @Sextus You're welcome.